# Retrieving data from file and storing in variable c#

Tags: c#

I want to create a file in which I can write certain text and then store it in variables because I must change the text depending on the PC they are on.My question is what type of file should I write my text in? (.txt , .xml , .xls , .etc) I know you can do on any type you want but for what type of file is c# built to do such a task?

To be more clearer (because I know I have a problem expressing what I want ) I will give an example.

#### Text file:

```
SN:123321123
PCName:blabla
Something.else:Text
```

And I would like to extract `123321123` and store it in a variable SN a.s.o. from my perspective I think I should store them in excel files to return them using `sheet.get_Range("first", last);` ,but I want to know if there is a simpler way?

Comment: C# isn't "built" for any file type, but its native XML support in the .net framework is excellent and well suited to this kind of task. A quick google of .net XML serialization should get you all the sample code you need.

Comment: I would suggest XML, just like LDJ did.

Comment: I found codes for that,that is not a problem.My question is about what is better to use? :)

Comment: Agree with XML. JSON also has good support and produces smaller files, if that's a consideration. Certainly don't use Excel.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be readable you could just serialise a struct :)

Comment: I recommend people give answers and we can see which have more up votes so I can chose from one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XML, there is lots of support and documentation on how to do this online. Another arguably 'cleaner' result would be JSON. This uses a simple key value pair relationship which is similar to the example you posted. But both are good.

XML Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>XML example</description>
 </book>
</catalog>
```

JSON Example:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "A green door",
   "price": 12.50,
   "tags": ["home", "green"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `XmlSerializer` to achieve this. It helps you to store and retrieve the objects in disk and the RAM.

> XML serialization is the process of converting an object's public properties and fields to a serial format (in this case, XML) for storage or transport. Deserialization re-creates the object in its original state from the XML output. You can think of serialization as a way of saving the state of an object into a stream or buffer. For example, ASP.NET uses the XmlSerializer class to encode XML Web service messages.
>   The data in your objects is described using programming language constructs like classes, fields, properties, primitive types, arrays, and even embedded XML in the form of XmlElement or XmlAttribute objects. You have the option of creating your own classes, annotated with attributes, or using the XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe) to generate the classes based on an existing XML Schema definition (XSD) document. If you have an XML Schema, you can run the Xsd.exe to produce a set of classes that are strongly typed to the schema and annotated with attributes to adhere to the schema when serialized.
>   To transfer data between objects and XML requires a mapping from the programming language constructs to XML schema and from the XML schema to the programming language constructs. The XmlSerializer and related tools like Xsd.exe provide the bridge between these two technologies at both design time and runtime. At design time, use the Xsd.exe to produce an XML schema document (.xsd) from your custom classes or to produce classes from a given schema. In either case, the classes are annotated with custom attributes to instruct the XmlSerializer how to map between the XML schema system and the common language runtime. At runtime, instances of the classes can be serialized into XML documents that follow the given schema. Likewise, these XML documents can be deserialized into runtime objects. Note that the XML schema is optional, and not required at design time or runtime.

For more information refer to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)